# How to reload environment variables in docker-compose container with minimum downtime?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: python src/app.py
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - TJBOT_DB_HOST=db
      - TJBOT_API_KEY
      - TJBOT_AUTO_QUESTION_TIME
    env_file:
      - .env
  db:
    image: mongo:3.0.14
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodbdata:
```

If I change the `.env` file, how could I reload the container to use the new environment variables with minimum downtime?

Comment: Can't think of a good way other than `down` then `up`. Some hacky horror around `docker exec` if you don't wanna do that? If they change that much maybe externalise them to something like consul?

Comment: The problem is that using `down` and `up` reloads all services, but I want to reload just my application service. I think this is the easiest way, but for many services it can take a while.

Comment: `docker-comypose restart service` **should** reload environment variables... This is completely an anti-pattern...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger it does not. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/

Comment: restart did nothing for me. only up -d did trick. Pay attention to data lost if ur data volume not mounted to host

Answer (score 219, accepted):

If you are running the yml with docker-compose, you can just run `docker-compose up -d` and it will recreate any containers that have changes and leave all unchanged services untouched.

```
$ cat docker-compose.env2.yml
version: '2'

services:
  test:
    image: busybox
    # command: env
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      - MY_VAR=hello
      - MY_VAR2=world
  test2:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      - MY_VAR=same ole same ole

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.env2.yml up -d                                               
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_test_1
Creating test_test2_1

$ vi docker-compose.env2.yml # edit the file to change MY_VAR

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.env2.yml up -d
Recreating test_test_1
test_test2_1 is up-to-date
```

If you run the containers as a `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml` with a version 3 file format, you can do a rolling update of the service which will prevent any downtime if you have multiple instances of your service running. This functionality is still very new, you'll want 1.13.1 to fix some of the issues with updates, and as with anything this new, bugs are still being worked out.

Comment: I removed the `.env` file, added a new `docker-compose.prod.yml` file and overriden the default settings: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d`

Comment: FYI: with compose version 3.7 `docker-compose up -d` worked for me also when referencing `env_file:` in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: FYI -d is the flag for Detached mode: Run containers in the background

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me and dont want to restart everything you can run
`docker compose up <service-name> -d`