# Can I change the enviroment setting without re building the docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So as I sit and develop my Rails application and I move more settings into the environment section of my docker compose file. I then shut down all containers and rebuild the image. Seems like a lot of work.

Can it be updated without rebuilding the image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change your env variables in your docker-compose file. And `docker-compose up -d` will updates your variables without rebuild images.
Rebuild images is necessary if you change your dockerfile.

Check this [How to reload environment variables in docker-compose container with minimum downtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149529/how-to-reload-environment-variables-in-docker-compose-container-with-minimum-dow)

Comment: Important note: `docker-compose restart` is not enough, it has to be `docker-compose up -d`