# Environment variables are not updating after changes in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to deploy mysql server on docker and when I try to change enviroment variables in my docker-compose.yml file they just don't change when I do `docker-compose up`.
I have noticed, that when I will remove container using `docker container remove <process ID>` and again try to `docker-compose up` it will works. If I will change name of the service in docker-compose.yml it will work too. Do I have always to remove stopped containers to restart enviroments variables or am I doing something wrong?

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password1'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password1'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reload environment variables in docker-compose container with minimum downtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149529/how-to-reload-environment-variables-in-docker-compose-container-with-minimum-dow)

Comment: no, it doesn't, I checked many topics like this and in most of cases they use env variables with different syntax like `- TJBOT_DB_HOST=db`

Comment: That's compose file version 2 syntax. It does not matter. Please at least READ what people send you. `docker-compose up -d` is what you are looking for. You must use a .env file though and reference that in your docker-compose.yml. "Does this answer your question?" is a automatic response and a nice way of saying "hey, that is a duplicate.".

Comment: Okey, everything is all right, I noticed, that if I change variable and then just do `docker-compose up` and print it by `echo $MYSQL_USER` in container CLI it will be updated. I thought it isn't because the login/password didn't change in mySQL connection.